# как добавить alert dialog в каждом items в android compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я начинал работать на android compose я сделал лист и при клике хочу добавить alert diolog как это сделать? [image: Сдесь я обработаю id каждого item - a]